# What would be the Mage::getSingleton('core/layout') in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, magento2-dev-beta

In Magento 1 I can Inject a template through coding like below.

```
$layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
$block = $layout->createBlock('module/module_block_identifier');
$block->setTemplate('module/test.phtml');
```

In Magento 2, how can I inject a template like above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using:

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Magento\Backend\Block\Template'
        )->setTemplate('module/test.phtml');
```

Class `\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout` as `Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')`

Answer (score 9):

If you are inside a block class you can simply use:

```
$layout = $this->getLayout(); 
....
```

If you are in a controller you need to inject in the constructor an instace of `\Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory` and use that:

```
protected $layoutFactory;
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory,
    ....
) {
    ...
    $this->layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;
    ...
}
```

And later you can use this:

```
$layout = $this->layoutFactory->create(); 
$block = $layout->createBlock(....)
```